# Block specific settings in Android

Tags: google-play-store, settings, lock-screens, accessibility, private-dns

Is this possible to block a specific setting in Android using accessibility permission and if yes then how can it be implemented? The best example I can find is this app named Cleanbrowsing and it is also not available on Play Store as it violates the policies of PlayStore.

[image: I can add multiple screens here and they will be locked.]

This app is not that great and sometimes it does not work. If you know any such app please include it in answers and guide me on how this can be implemented.